# "you are not allowed to access this page" error when using add_submenu_page

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the add_submenu_page function of wp to add a sub menu inside a parent men, but I'm getting this error when accessing that submenu:

> Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.

I'm logged in as admin, flushed permalinks and logged out then logged in but nothing is changing.

my code:

```
class SPSetup {

    public function reg_func() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'sp_menu', ) );
    }

    public function sp_menu() {
        add_submenu_page( 
            'montheme_options', 'SP Dashboard', 'SP Dashboard', 
            'manage_options', 'sp-control', 
            array( $this, 'callback' ) 
        );
    }      
}


if ( class_exists( 'SPSetup ' ) ) {
    $SP= new SPSetup ();
    $SP->reg_func();
}
```

Comment: The required capability there is `manage_options`. Who are you logged in as and with what Role? https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: @jaswrks I'm logged in as admin and can use dashboard settings, change themes and all sort of thing admin do. that's not it.

Comment: Usually it's because the slug of your sub menu is missing from the URL.  What does the page URL look like?

Comment: @AndrewSchultz I changed the slug (before the callback func) from sp-control to sp_control and now I'm getting a 404 error. My url is localhost/wp-admin/sp_control

Comment: That doesn't look correct at all.  It should look something like this dependent on where the menu has been added, this is for the settings menu /wp-admin/options-general.php?page=my-custom-options

Comment: @AndrewSchultz yes, it looks incorrect. I used 'tools.php' and that worked but I want my submenu under a custom parent menu added by a theme. This is how they added their parent menu: `add_menu_page( 'MonTheme', 'MonTheme', 'switch_themes', 'montheme_options', 'mt_theme_options_dashboard' );` so which slug I should use?

Comment: You need to use the function add_submenu_page( string $parent_slug, string $page_title, string $menu_title, string $capability, string $menu_slug, callable $function = '' ) if you want to add a child menu under a parent.

Comment: As you can see in my code I'm already using it. Thanks!

Comment: As you can see in my code I'm already using it. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I had same issue.
Try to add priority in 'admin_menu' hook and remove hyphens from submenu slug.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'sp_menu'), 11);
```

This solved my problem.

Also check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91377/admin-menu-as-submenu-from-another-plugin

Answer (score 6):

**TLDR**: Add a lower priority, such as 99, to the action that creates the submenu page.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpdocs_register_my_custom_submenu_page', 99 );
```

In my case I was trying to add a submenu to a preinstalled plugin menu so I got the same error.

Thanks to **isabel104** and her comment I solved it:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/#div-comment-4596

Regarding the 1st note in the More Information section above, you may also run into the “Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.” message even if you’ve hooked correctly into the admin_menu hook. This error message will happen if all of these are true:

Your parent page is a custom page that you added using add_menu_page, and
That parent page was created in another plugin, not the same plugin that is creating the submenu page, and
You didn’t add a lower priority to the admin_menu hook for the add_submenu_page call, so the submenu page may be fired before the parent page–causing an error.

**Solution**: Add a lower priority, such as 99, to the action that creates the submenu page. For example:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpdocs_register_my_custom_submenu_page', 99 );
```

Comment: Thanks, the change of priority was the solution.